# socket.io.js not found on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This question has been asked previously but haven't found any solution in prior replies.

Socket.IO gives me two problems:

1. server side gave this error - ERROR - listen EACESS
   I read stackoverflow and resolved this with issuing a sudo command to start the server.
2. now clientside doesnt seem to find the socket.io.js file as per the script line  -

I understand file is not found by using the chrome developer tools console which has a 404 error on the file.

I read that this file is created on the fly by server. But I did a 'ls-a' on the root folder. Couldn't find the socket.io/socket.io.js file.

Any ideas?

For reference here is my server code -

```
var http = require('http'),
  path = require("path"),
  url = require("url"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  mime = require("mime"),
  io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var homepath = ".";
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  var filepath = path.join(homepath, uri);
  console.log(filepath);
  path.exists(filepath, function (exists) {
    if (!exists) {
      //404 response
      res.writeHead(404, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      });
      res.write("404 File not Found \n");
      res.end();
    } else {
      if (fs.statSync(filepath).isDirectory()) {
        filepath += '/index.html';
        filepath = path.normalize(filepath);
      }
      fs.readFile(filepath, "binary", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.writeHead(500, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
          });
          res.write('500 File read error \n');
          res.end();
        } else {
          var contentType = mime.lookup(filepath);
          res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': contentType
          });
          res.write(data, 'binary');
          res.end();
        }
      });
    }
  });
  //sockets part starts here
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('test', function (data) {
      console.log('i got something');
      console.log(data.print);
    });
  });
});
server.listen(3000);
server.on('error', function (e) {
  console.log(e);
});
console.log('Server listening on Port 3000');
```

Comment: Did you install using npm?

Comment: yes i did install via npm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you're telling Socket.IO to listen on a server that does not yet exist, causing an `EACCES` and therefore not serving the client file. This is what you're doing:

```
// the HTTP server doesn't exist yet
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var server = http.createServer();
```

And if you saw in your server-side error console, you get this:

```
info: socket.io started
warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES
```

To fix this, move your listen function to after the server is created:

```
var server = http.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Once Socket.IO listens properly, it will automatically serve the client file to `/socket.io/socket.io.js`. You don't need to find it or serve it manually.

Answer (score 2):

The client file that you need is located inside the node_modules folder here:

```
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js
```

Socket.io should serve this file though so you don't need to copy it somewhere else. For example if you are running your socket.io server on:

```
http://localhost:5000
```

Then the script will be served from:

```
http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

If you are consuming socket.io from another application or another port the relative URL in your code example won't work. You'll want to include the client-script manually or try including the client node module (if consumed by node app).

You can view the client repository here for more info:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client

Comment: I am using node.js only. The port is 3000.However i have manually created a fileserver in nodejs without using express. So the server code would try to find a file located at socket.io/socket.io.js which it would not find. How would things work out then?

Comment: There's no file on disk at socket.io/socket.io.js. It's being served dynamically by socket.io from a different location  (see the method here https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L145). If you're handling it yourself it's probably never getting to socket.io for this request.